# TRICKY Rolling Sum Query with Reset

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that there are 6 months of historical data with hundreds of rides per day:

***Write a query that returns, for each of the last 90 days, a count of the rides taken in the 7 day window preceding that day***

I would like to find a way to write this in **MySQL** but have had some trouble with having a rolling sum that resets along with how I could cut up timestamps to reflect a day of the year/date and to then group by that.

I have tried writing subqueries that will limit the sum to a week prior and then place an additional limit of 90 days after that but cannot seem to get the code to return any output.

I have tried writing this is PostgreSQL using a sort of "window" functionality but am much more comfortable working in MySQL and would like to be able to solve it that way. I am familiar on how to write limits, group and order among other things but I am having trouble with the rolling sum resetting per week.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could update your question to include the queries you've tried along with a few example data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want a numbers table/query. There are some tricky CTE ways to do that but it might be easier for now just to add a table with the numbers 1-90 in 90 rows.

Then use that to generate, for each row, a date range. Sorry if the syntax isn't quite correct, but write a query along the lines: 
`SELECT num, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -(num+7) DAY) startdate, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -num DAY) enddate FROM numbers`

Then you can cross-join that with your rides table grouped on num and counting the rows in the range:

`SELECT num, startdate, enddate, SUM(CASE WHEN startdate <= ridedate AND ridedate <= 
    enddate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ridecount
    FROM (date range query) dts, rides
    GROUP BY dts.num`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data on each day, a correlated subquery might be simplest approach:

```
select dt,
       (select count(*)
        from rides r
        where r.ridedate >= d.dte - interval 7 day and
              r.ridedate < d.date
       ) as rolling_7
from (select distinct ridedate as dt
      from rides
     ) dt
```